# jQuery - Replace spaces within all Option Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, loops, replace

I have a returned JSON string which I have parsed and put through into an array and then formatted to put into a select dropdown list:

```
   function populateGroups(){
        var categories = '';
        for( category in gCategories ){
            categories += '<option name="' + gCategories[category] + '">' + gCategories[category] + '</option>';
            categories.replace(' ', '_');
        }
        $('select[name="category"]').html(categories);    
    }
```

The problem I have is that the option names (which are the same as the values) contain spaces which I need to replace with something that would be valid, such as an underscore '_'.

That is why I have tried doing the categories.replace(' ', '_'); I have also tried doing this with regex, although my RegEx is not very good :P

Any ideas on how this would be done?

Thanks!

[Note]
Here is the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pKYr4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the string as well;

```
categories = categories.replace(/ /g, '_');
```

...a problem though is that not just the values are formated/trimmed as `<option name="...`  will be affected as well.

```
<option_name="category_value">category_value</option>
```

This can be solved this way;

```
function populateGroups() {
    var categories = '';
    for( c in gCategories ) {
        var categoryValue = gCategories[c].replace(/ /g, '_');
        categories += '<option name="' + categoryValue + '">' + gCategories[c] + '</option>';
    }
    $('select[name="category"]').html(categories);    
}
```

Comment: ^+1 exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you pass a string to `replace`, it replaces only the first occurrence.

You should use `.replace(/ /g, '_')` instead. The g flag is for global.

And I guess you don't want to run that on the markup string, but only for the category, otherwise you'll have `<option_name=...`

Could be something like:

```
    for (category in gCategories ) {
        var noSpaceCategory = gCategories[category].replace(/ /g, '_');
        categories += '<option name="' + noSpaceCategory + '">' + gCategories[category] + '</option>';
    }
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yK8sM.png - That is the result of : http://i.imgur.com/BpIHb.png Which is what you said, but it still doens't seem to work :/

Comment: updated the answer. If it doesn't help create a jsfiddle to share the code. Images are nasty

Comment: That works brilliantly. That is exactly what I want ^^ Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript trim for removing spaces, see: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript. If you'd like to replace them with dashses:

`var str = gCategories[category];`

`str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
function replaceAll(txt, replace, with_this) {
  return txt.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'),with_this);
}
```

which can be called like this:

```
replaceAll('1,000,000', ',', '')
```

could work...